# USB storage recognized on linux, not windows, mkfs in which type?

Tags: linux, usb-storage

I have a key that have been infected by the famous virus which transform files to shortcut.
I ve done USBFix to clean it, and put it on a raspberry pi, I saw files in normal and .lnk form, and erased everything. (`sudo rm -r /media/usb/*`).

But now, windows don t recognized it, so I thought I ll reformat it from the raspberry.

`ls -al /sbin/ | grep mkfs` bring me this:

```
mkfs
mkfs.bfs
mkfs.cramfs
mkfs.ext2
mkfs.ext3
mkfs.ext4
mkfs.ext4dev
mkfs.minix
```

Which one would be recognized by windows so I can use the device again?

Comment: You need VFAT or NTFS file system

Comment: Urg, so I ll need to find another linux. You can post as answer if you want me to accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can install the `ntfs-3g` package which will give you `mkfs.ntfs` or install the `dosfstools` package to get `mkfs.vfat` assuming you're using Raspbian.

Simple as `apt-get install dosfstools` for example. Then you will get `mkfs.vfat`.