# USB storage bricked? (0kb on windows AND linux)

Tags: windows-7, ubuntu-12.04, usb-storage

[Same device as on this question](https://superuser.com/questions/722830/usb-storage-recognized-on-linux-not-windows-mkfs-in-which-type)

I have a device which has been infected with a malware (the one which transform file to .lnk, windows shortcut). After cleaning, it didn t show on windows, but on linux.

I ended up to dd /dev/zero on it, the time to get mkfs.ntfs (even thought it take way much time to wipe than download) to be sure the malware were truly gone.

Now, mkfs say the device is 0kb, as do windows.

Did I just brick the USB storage?

Comment: This is a *troubleshooting* question, which is [likely to involve a lot of back and forth in the comments](http://meta.superuser.com/a/6838/144607). Instead, come on over to [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/118/root-access) and we'll extract the information we need from you, like pulling teeth with pliers. Don't worry, we won't use any novocaine on you first, to ensure maximum pain sensation >:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/14036856#14036856

> dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sdc (where sdc is whatever block device it was) will *wipe out the partition table as well*
>
> as a matter of fact, just to be sure the malware isn't hiding in the MBR, I'd go ahead and wipe the partition table anyway

General idea:

1. Put a new MBR or GPT partition table on the device using `parted`, `gparted`, `cfdisk`, or even Windows' own Computer Management MMC snap-in, depending on what's convenient for you.
2. Reformat it.
3. If it doesn't work, it's probably bricked, but it is not likely to be due to the `dd` command -- more likely is that the NAND chips gave up due to the number of times they've been overwritten, which could mean your device is just old and worn out.
4. If it works, that was the problem ;)